# Why are trees referred to in female form in ברכת האילנות?

Tags: blessing, trees, nissan, grammatical-gender

On Nissan we say ברכת האילנות on blossoming fruit trees. The nusach of the bracha is:

> בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה' אֱלֹקֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם, שֶׁלֹּא חִסֵּר בָּעוֹלָמוֹ כְּלוּם, וּבָרָא בּוֹ בְּרִיּוֹת טוֹבוֹת וְאִילָנוֹת טוֹבוֹת וְנָאוֹת, (כְּדֵי) לֵהָנוֹת בָּהֶן בְּנֵי אָדָם.

Why are trees referred to in the female form (i.e. "אִילָנוֹת טוֹבוֹת וְנָאוֹת") and not in its normal masculine form?

Comment: Why is the Rambam's chapter called מאכלות אסורות? Why next week will some observe תענית בכורות in commemoration of מכת בכורות? That's just the form that's used. Maybe modern Hebrew or Biblical Hebrew, or Rabbinic Hebrew have different tendencies for how to treat that word, but who cares?

Comment: https://www.shoresh.org.il/usersfiles/pps/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%9F.pdf

Comment: Is this just a Hebrew language-oriented question?

Comment: @DoubleAA תענית בכורות and מכת בכורות don't show the word is being treated as feminine -- merely that it has a feminine-like plural ending (which is not that uncommon for masculine nouns). Use of a feminine adjective otoh shows that the noun is being treated as feminine. And that's much more unusual (though, as you say, it happens also in מאכלות אסורות).

Comment: @msh210 So what's happening with אילנות? Is it a masc. noun that's being treated as fem. in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://www.plantvillage.org/en/questions/404-pear-pear-trees-that-don-t-produce-fruit) on Plantvillage.org

> A few tree fruits require individual male and female trees; in other
>   words female trees have only female flowers and bear fruit while male
>   trees only have male flowers that produce pollen.

Based on this, perhaps the Nusach of the Bracha is in the female form as there are some male trees that do not produce fruit on them.

Comment: So, אילנות would be a plural of אילנה ?

Comment: @paquda: אילני טובים ונאים is the male form