# What is the longest "short" bracha?

Tags: blessing, statistics

What is the longest "short" bracha? (By a short bracha I mean one that begins with baruach ata ha-shem ... and ends with the subject matter of the bracha, with no second baruch ata ha-shem.)  (I am thinking of length in terms of number of words.)

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Please edit to motivate your question

Comment: As noted in comments, both of the existing answers seem to fail one the criteria according to certain authorities. You may want to clarify if your question is according to a particular authority, any authority, every authority, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Longest I can think of is the fourth beracha of bentching. It’s not clear where it ends, but at a minimum (Nusach Ashkenaz):

> בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה', אֱלֹהֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם, הָאֵל אָבִינוּ מַלְכֵּנוּ אַדִירֵנוּ בּוֹרְאֵנוּ גּוֹאֲלֵנוּ יוֹצְרֵנוּ קְדוֹשֵׁנוּ קְדוֹשׁ יַעֲקֹב רוֹעֵנוּ רוֹעֵה יִשְׂרָאַל הַמֶּלֶךְ הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב לַכּל שֶׁבְּכָל יוֹם וָיוֹם הוּא הֵטִיב, הוּא מֵטִיב, הוּא יֵיטִיב לָנוּ. הוּא גְמָלָנוּ הוּא גוֹמְלֵנוּ הוּא יִגְמְלֵנוּ לָעַד, לְחֵן וּלְחֶסֶד וּלְרַחֲמִים וּלְרֶוַח הַצָּלָה וְהַצְלָחָה, בְּרָכָה וִישׁוּעָה נֶחָמָה פַּרְנָסָה וְכַלְכָּלָה וְרַחֲמִים וְחַיִּים וְשָׁלוֹם וְכָל טוֹב, וּמִכָּל טוּב לְעוֹלָם עַל יְחַסְּרֵנוּ.

- According to the [Shach, YD 379:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.379.1?lang=bi&p2=Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.379.1.1&lang2=bi), from [Berachos 46b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.46b.4), in a house of mourning the phrase המלך הטוב והמטיב לכל is replaced with the following (as opposed to replacing most of the blessing, as the Shulchan Aruch ad. loc. writes):

> הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב, אֵל אֱמֶת, דַּיַּין אֱמֶת, שׁוֹפֵט בְּצֶדֶק, לוֹקֵחַ בַּמִּשְׁפָּט, וְשַׁלִּיט בְּעוֹלָמוֹ לַעֲשׂוֹת בּוֹ כִּרְצוֹנוֹ, כִּי כׇל דְּרָכָיו מִשְׁפָּט, שֶׁהַכֹּל שֶׁלּוֹ וַאֲנַחְנוּ עַמּוֹ וַעֲבָדָיו, וּבַכֹּל אֲנַחְנוּ חַיָּיבִים לְהוֹדוֹת לוֹ וּלְבָרְכוֹ, גּוֹדֵר פְּרָצוֹת בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל הוּא יִגְדּוֹר אֶת הַפִּרְצָה הַזֹּאת בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל לְחַיִּים

- According to the [Rambam, Berachos 2:7](https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&hilchos=10&perek=2&halocha=7), the insertion said by a guest is a  part of this blessing as well, and thus the following can also be appended to the blessing (and whatever else the guest wants to add, extending the beracha to be arbitrarily long!):

> יְהִי רָצוֹן שֶׁלֹּא יֵבוֹשׁ בַּעַל הַבַּיִת בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה, וְלֹא יִכָּלֵם לְעוֹלָם הַבָּא וְיִצְלַח מְאֹד בְּכָל נְכָסָיו, וְיִהְיוּ נְכָסָיו וּנְכָסֵינוּ מוּצְלָחִים וּקְרוֹבִים לָעִיר, וְאַל יִשְׁלוֹט שָׂטָן לֹא בְּמַעֲשֵׂי יָדָיו וְלֹא בְּמַעֲשֵׂי יָדֵינוּ, וְאַל יִזְדַּקֵּר לֹא לְפָנָיו וְלֹא לְפָנֵינוּ שׁוּם דְּבַר הִרְהוּר חֵטְא וַעֲבֵירָה וְעָוֹן מֵעַתָּה וְעַד עוֹלָם

(h/t DoubleAA and Heshy on these latter extensions.)

Comment: The variant for a house of mourning is longer (at least, according to some, bach/shach etc.)

Comment: @DoubleAA https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.379.1?p2=Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.379.1.1 was about to say the same thing

Comment: Also it's even longer for a guest https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&hilchos=10&perek=2&halocha=7

Comment: According to R. Yosi Hagelili (Tosefta Berachos 1:9) this fails the criterion of not having a chasimah.

Comment: @Alex We don't pasken like R' Yosi Hagelili though.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a long one:

> בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם, שֶׁלֹּא חִסֵּר בְּעוֹלָמוֹ כְּלוּם, וּבָרָא בוֹ בְּרִיוֹת טוֹבוֹת וְאִילָנוֹת טוֹבוֹת, לֵהָנוֹת בָּהֶם בְּנֵי אָדָם:

Comment: According to the Ra'avad on the Rif at the beginning of Chapter 9 of Berachos, this presumably fails the criterion of having God's name in the beginning of the blessing. As noted [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90405/13438), according to the Perisha this may even be the common practice.

Comment: Some related question for the record: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70376/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/112251/15256